# How to change the size of my drawer menu icon?

Tags: flutter

I researched a lot and did not find how to do it. I need to change the icon size, how do I do this? follow my code below.

```
      return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: Radius.circular(50)),
      child: Container(
        width:size.isMobile ? 282 : 450,
        child:Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomHeader(
                userName: widget.userName,
              ),
              IconSection(),
              Divider(color: Colors.grey[500],),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 210,
                      child: Image.asset("images/LogoBetsOnline.png"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can you share your UI ?

Comment: You should  create custom drawer.

Comment: do you mean the icon that you press to open the drawer?

Comment: this, I'm talking about the icon menu that comes by default from the drawer

Answer (score 0):

Use Column instead of ListView

```
       Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 200,
              child: Image.asset(
                'demo.png',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```